# Is it possible to arrange charts based on the same chart title -same chart title in one row

Tags: excel, vba

I have many charts in a worksheet which I want to arrange in an order.I got the code to arrange 3 charts in a row but what I want is the charts with same title to be in a same row.

```
 Sub CHART_ARRANGE()

' chart size - adjust as desired
' set one or both to zero to use dimensions of active chart
'   (or first chart if no chart is active)
Const nRowsTall As Long = 0
Const nColsWide As Long = 0

' chart layout - adjust as desired
Const nChartsPerRow As Long = 3
Const nSkipRows As Long = 2
Const nSkipCols As Long = 1
Const nFirstRow As Long = 1
Const nFirstCol As Long = 1

Dim iChart As Long
Dim chtob As ChartObject
Dim dWidth As Double
Dim dHeight As Double
Dim rData As Range
Dim dFirstChartTop As Double
Dim dFirstChartLeft As Double
Dim dRowsBetweenChart As Double
Dim dColsBetweenChart As Double

If ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then

With ActiveSheet.Cells(nFirstRow, nFirstCol)
  If nRowsTall * nColsWide > 0 Then
    dWidth = nColsWide * .Width
    dHeight = nRowsTall * .Height
  Else
    If Not ActiveChart Is Nothing Then
      Set chtob = ActiveChart.Parent
    Else
      Set chtob = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)
    End If
    dWidth = chtob.Width
    dHeight = chtob.Height
  End If

  dFirstChartLeft = .Left
  dFirstChartTop = .Top
  dRowsBetweenChart = nSkipRows * .Height
  dColsBetweenChart = nSkipCols * .Width
End With

For iChart = 1 To ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count

  Set chtob = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(iChart)

  With chtob
    .Left = ((iChart - 1) Mod nChartsPerRow) * _
        (dWidth + dColsBetweenChart) + dFirstChartLeft
    .Top = Int((iChart - 1) / nChartsPerRow) * _
        (dHeight + dRowsBetweenChart) + dFirstChartTop
    .Width = dWidth
    .Height = dHeight
  End With

Next

End If

End Sub
```

[image]
how do I modify the code to get charts with same title to be on same row like the above graphs.

Comment: Have you tried using the macro recorder whilst manually selecting charts and doing the align top etc in Excel?

Comment: I was not expecting that recording will help me as I would see the chart title and move the chart accordingly. The charts dont have any good name. But Chart title with same name need to moved

Answer (score 0):

The real coding depends on the exact requirements. I made a quick example that arranges all charts by title. It has some limitations (for example it doesn't do a sort) and puts all charts with same title on the same row.

The code uses a dictionary with the chart title as keys and a logical position (containing row and col) and value.

It loops over all charts, fetches the title and checks if the title is already in the dictionary. If yes, it gets the position of the previous chart with the same title and increases the logical column by 1. If not, a new logical row is added into the dictionary (with row = size of the dictionary and col = 0).

The chart is placed by calculating `Width` and `Height` using the logical position multiplied by some constants.

```
Sub sortChartsByTitle()

    Const startX = 50    ' Left margin
    Const startY = 50    ' Top margin
    Const deltaX = 400 
    Const deltay = 260

    Dim chartTitleList As Dictionary, co As ChartObject
    Dim chartPos As cPos

    Set chartTitleList = New Dictionary
    For Each co In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        Dim title As String
        title = ""
        If co.Chart.HasTitle Then
            title = co.Chart.ChartTitle.Text    ' Get ChartTitle (if any)
        End If
        If title = "" Then
            title = "(no title)"    ' Set a default if chart has no title or title is empty
        End If

        If chartTitleList.Exists(title) Then
            ' There was already one chart with same title.
            Set chartPos = chartTitleList(title) ' Get logical position 
            chartPos.col = chartPos.col + 1      ' Jump one to the left
            Set chartTitleList(title) = chartPos ' Remember thus new position
        Else
            Set chartPos = New cPos              ' Create a new logical position
            chartPos.row = chartTitleList.Count  ' Row = size of dictionary
            chartPos.col = 0                     ' Col = 0
            Call chartTitleList.Add(title, chartPos) ' Add to Dictionary
        End If

        ' Position chart
        co.Left = startX + chartPos.col * deltaX
        co.Top = startY + chartPos.row * deltay
    Next co
End Sub
```

You need a object type to hold the logical position, so add a class module named `cPos`. All you need there is (of course you can wrap this with setter and getter...)

```
Option Explicit

Public row As Integer
Public col As Integer
```

Comment: it throws error saying -user- defined type not defined

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that you have to add a reference to the `Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime`